# convert all csv files from s3 to parquet

Tags: python

What I am going to do is converting all files form S3( AWS Storage) to parquet format and re-save those into s3.

I cannot come up with converting all files from s3. Please help me !!

```py
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
from s3fs import S3FileSystem
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

s3 = boto3.client('s3',region_name='us-east-2')

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='dstest-s3', Key='dstest/movies.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

output_file = "s3://dstest-s3/dstest/parquetconversion1.parquet"
s3 = S3FileSystem()

pq.write_to_dataset(table=table, root_path=output_file, filesystem=s3)

print("File converted from CSV to parquet completed")
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to fetch all of the keys from the bucket using [list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) and iterate over the keys, download, convert, and upload.

```
s3 = bt3.get_client('s3')
response = s3.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket='dstest-s3',
        Prefix='dstest/'
)

for s3_obj in response['Contents']:
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='dstest-s3', Key=s3_obj['Key'])
    # Do your converting, and uploading here
```